# Image not appearing making img source at span in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in coding javascript/ajax. I have an ajax gathering the workers photo for my project in school. Now I want to display my photo inside of `<output="list"></output>` HTML tag through javascript. I've already got the value from my database, but my problem is about putting the value inside the output tag using javascript.

Here is what I did :

```
function edit_emp(id){        
        save_method = 'update';
        $('#form')[0].reset(); 
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');  
        $('.help-block').empty(); 
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('HumanE/ajax_edit/')?>" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data){
                document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="'+data.worker_photo+'"'];
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);               
                $('#modal_form').modal('show'); 
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Employee details'); 
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    text: 'A process cannot get through. Please consult your admin.',
                    type: 'error',
                    styling: 'bootstrap3'
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the full code of my output tag:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
  <label for="supid">Employee Picture</label>
  <output id="list"></output>
  <div class="upimage">
     <input class="form-control" required type="file" id="file" name="file"/>      
  </div>                                
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a span and then inserting the element, try the following as the success function:

```
 success: function(data){
    var output_list = document.getElementById('list');
    var img_elem = document.createElement("img");
    img_elem.classList.add("thumb");
    img_elem.src = data.worker_photo;
    output_list.appendChild(img_elem);
    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); 
    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Employee details'); 
 }
```

Comment: hello sir, i got this two errors from console
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More]
ReferenceError: elem is not defined[Learn More]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.classList.add("thumb");
img.src = data.worker_photo;
// If you want to clear the span first
span.innerHTML = "";
span.appendChild(img.cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: hello sir i am getting 304 Not Modified

Comment: and an error of TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More]

Comment: @JcJohn I would check this statement then: ```document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null); ```

Comment: @JcJohn Does an element with an id of ```list``` exist in your document?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ImageHTML = '< img class="thumb" src="'+data.worker_photo+'" >';

$('#list').html(ImageHTML);
```

Comment: $.ajax() --> this is jQuery function